# How to return the name of the variable with maximum value from an array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have been trying to return `a` instead of `100` in Javascript?

However, I believe I am doing something wrong with my loop.

```js
let a = 100
let b = 25
let c = 75
let d = 50
let A = [a,b,c,d]

function solution(A) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    let result = []
    let max = Math.max(...A)
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    if (A[i] === max){
      return A[i]
    }
    return A
}
console.log( solution(A))
```

Comment: The array `A` doesn't know about what variables you used to populate it. It only knows the values. I would try putting `a-d` in a struct, using the letters as keys, then passing the struct to `solution()` and returning the matching key.

Comment: @user1599011 is struct the same as object?

Comment: sorry, yes. I use CFML for backend, which calls them structs. I tried to edit my comment, but was outside the 5-minute time limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@user1599011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71310612/how-to-return-the-name-of-the-variable-with-maximum-value-from-an-array-using-ja#comment126048568_71310612) mentioned, this is not possible using an array as your example.

---

I'd recommend using an object, with the key's as desired, and the value as the integer. We can use the the [shorthand object syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to create the object like so:

```
let A = { a, b, c, d };
```

---

Then you can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to search for the key with the heights value:

```js
let a = 100
let b = 25
let c = 75
let d = 50
let A = { a, b, c, d };

function solution(A) {
    return Object.keys(A).reduce((prev, cur) => A[prev] > A[cur] ? prev : cur);
}

console.log(solution(A)); // a
```

Comment: interesting your code makes a lot of sense. I was wondering if it possible to make a new object (i.e object B) that takes array A and the variables a,b, c and d instead?  Like can I keep the array A as it is and just make an Object B with {a,b,c,d}, if so how?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You can create the original array `A` as you do in your example. Could you maybe give an example?

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, use an object. Pass that object to `solution()`; one way you can find and return the key of the highest value is to use `Object.entries()` to produce an array with `[key, value]`, e.g., `[a,100]`, as elements, sort by value in descending order then return the key of element in index `0`.

```js
let a = 100;
let b = 25;
let c = 75;
let d = 50;
let A = {a,b,c,d};

function solution(A) {
    return Object.entries(A).sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1])[0][0]
}
console.log( solution(A) )
```

***Note:*** If there are multiple keys with the highest value, this will return only one key.

Comment: thanks a lot, always great to see new ways of writing the code.

Comment: Note that using `sort` to find a maximum is heavyweight.  There are more efficient techniques (which will be irrelevant if the problem-space is small enough.)